# SSH: How could I know the concurrent limit?

Tags: python, ssl, ssh

In order to test SSH server, I created a test program (in python) on the client side. The test program will generate 100 processes, each process will make a SSH connection with the server. Any failed attempt will wait for 10 seconds and retry.

Here is my observation:

1. On the first 10 seconds, only 30 of the client could create a successful connection. 70 clients were rejected.
2. On the next 10 seconds, another 30 clients could create a successful connection. 40 were rejected.
3. On the next 10 seconds, another 30 clients could create a successful connection. 10 were rejected.
4. On the next 10 seconds, last 10 client could create a successful connection.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to make 100 successful secured connection in one go? Which SSH parameter (server side) I need to modify in order to achieve this?
2. Python has a built-in SSL library. If I use SSL to replace SSH, could I make 100 successful secured connection in one go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like your server has a maximum of 30 concurrent request handlers configured.

Comment: I can't parse "Is it possible to make secured connection in one go?". Do you mean "Is it possible to configure the ssh server to allow all 100 connections simultaneously?" If so, it depends on the ssh server you're using, so you'll have to specify.

Comment: SSL and SSH don't have much in common. You can't connect to a SSH server using SSL libraries.

Comment: Sorry I should make this clear.
     1. I would like to log in 100 concurrent connection in one go. Which SSH paramerters I need to modify?
     2. Is it possible to make 100 concurrent connection in one go, using SSL library?

Comment: @Winston Both should be possible. But both as well depending on server settings. There is no inherent limit on the number of connections done via the one or other encryption method. But encryption costs time, and 100 encryptions done in parallel might slow down things drastically.

Comment: @glglgl I think running 100 encryption will slow the things down. But there is a need to encrypt the data. Would there be any alternative?

Comment: @Winston Maybe less concurrency - if you run 20 connections at a time, it might be even faster than 100 at a time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to log in 100 concurrent connection in one go. Which SSH paramerters I need to modify?

Well, I asked you to specify which ssh server you were using, but since you didn't respond, I'll have to assume you're using [`openssh`](http://www.openssh.org/).

The only [`sshd_config(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) configuration parameter I can see which might affect the number of connections you can make 'simultaneously' is `MaxStartups`, for which the docs say...

> Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections
>   to the SSH daemon. Additional connections will be dropped until
>   authentication succeeds or the `LoginGraceTime` expires for a
>   connection.  The default is 10.
>
> Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
>   three colon separated values “start:rate:full” (e.g. "10:30:60"). 
>   sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of
>   “rate/100” (30%) if there are currently “start” (10) unauthenticated
>   connections.  The probability increases linearly and all connection
>   attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated connections
>   reaches “full” (60).

...so you'll probably have to set that value to at least 100.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the config file. The 'MaxStartups' value is commented therefore it is running the default value (10). However the test result above shows that the I am not running the at 10. But I will modify the value to 100 and see how it goes. Thanks for your help.